# How to create a driver for a usb scanner on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, usb, drivers

I'm currently running MacOS 10.12.1 and I have got an old usb scanner that I like to use, but it didn't come with a driver – only software that isn't supported on Sierra. Although I'm highly unqualified to do anything software related I would really like to create a driver so that my mac recognises this device. Looking around in the old software I found the following relevant .bundle file containing this information (which matches my device):

```
<CropOffset XValue="0" YValue="0" />
<OrgSize XValue="2544" YValue="1696" /> 

<AutoEnhance Support="1" />
<AutoColorBalance Support="0" />

<InputName Name="USB Scanner 5MP" />
<PID Number="50259" />
<VID Number="2760" />

<SlideWhiteBalance135 Value="3000" />
<NegativeWhiteBalance135 Value="5000" />
<BWNegativeWhiteBalance135 Value="6000" />  

<NegativeWhiteBalance110 Value="4000" />
<BWNegativeWhiteBalance110 Value="4000" />
```

My question is following, can I install this bundle file somehow or create a new usb driver with this information or do I need way more coding knowledge and with that just give up and purchase another product?

Comment: I'd give up & buy yourself a nice modern multi-function printer. I just treated myself to an HP MFP M477fdw [networked, wifi, touch-screen, bells, whistles.. the works] for less than the price of my first ever scanner & less than the price of new ink for my old MFP. It actually scans straight to the Mac which my old Samsung couldn't do... & it does it at about 15 ppm, my old one was about 1ppm.

Answer (score 0):

Giving up would be a fairly good idea. Unless you can get the manufacturer to create drivers for you, it would be hopelessly complicated trying to do something like this even for someone experienced in this.